# Storing luggage at Tokyo Narita Airport

Tags: luggage-storage, nrt

In August I will go to Japan to visit relatives and to make a trek. Since I would have both "normal" luggage and "trekking" luggage, I would like to leave my normal luggage somewhere to go on the trekking.

Is it possible to store a small suitcase at the Tokyo Narita Airport for about a week? Any idea of the costs involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any long-term storage like that.  There are plenty of luggage courier services at the airport who would be able to courier your suitcase anywhere in Japan for around $20USD.  I'd just courier it to your relatives.  You can either pick it up from them when you leave, or they can take it to any convenience store and get it sent to the airport for you.

---

EDIT:  I did some digging around and GPA offers baggage storage in both terminals.  Their rates are pretty reasonable, too.

```
Small Baggage:   310 yen / day
General Baggage: 520 yen / day
Large Baggage:   820 yen / day
```

They'll store your bags in their luggage room for up to 30 days.

Whoops, I didn't notice that I wasn't logged in when I made that edit.

Comment: The problem is that my relatives do not live in Tokyo, they only rent a place there and live in Hokaido, which is not around the corner.

Answer (score 2):

You can leave a suitcase in a [coin locker](http://www.narita-airport.jp/en/guide/service/list/svc_07.html) (can be paid by Suica also for those in T1) for up to 8 days. There are also some [baggage storage companies](http://www.narita-airport.jp/en/guide/service/list/svc_06.html), but their websites are only in Japanese.

Comment: Do you know the locker sizes by any chance? Thanks!

Comment: @kitkat They are not completely standardised, but you can use [this](http://www.jreast.co.jp/e/stations/pdf/info_coinlocker.pdf) as a general guideline. Note that the largest sizes are not available at all stations.

Answer (score 2):

I think minimum is 3 days..you pay the 300 to 500 yen first day depending on the locker size. After you pick it up (the day) it will ask the remaining charges before it allows you to open the locker box. If it laps three days there is a sign telling you where your items was transferred/moved to be claimed.. it will still be in the airport area. So make sure you be ready and give more time in the airport before you miss your flight.
As I recalled. I have left my items there for 2 days in the past trips.